# Is using QtFFmpegWrapper+QLabel+QTimer a good way to play video in a Qt application?

Tags: qt, video, ffmpeg, qlabel

I'm looking how to portably play video on Qt, but not Phonon.

Using ffmpeg seems to be a good idea (it should work the same way on all platforms).

Currently It uses QLabel for video output and does QPixmap::fromImage for each frame; frames which are decoded and buffered by [QtFFmpegWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/) in a background thread. QTimer decides when to show the next frame.

The whole thing looks a bit hacky (Video? In a *label*?). Am I doing it right? Is there a better portable way of playing ffmpeg-decoded video in a Qt application?

Comment: QLabel derives from QWidget, so it's as good a way as any to display the decoded frames.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look to Qt Multimedia module in Qt 5.0: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtmultimedia/qtmultimedia-index.html. It should be more efficient than the process you described (it depends on the platform).

EDIT: For versions previous to Qt 5.0 you can still try the [Qt Multimedia](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/examples-multimedia.html) module using the [Qt Multimedia Kit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/multimedia.html) compiling Qt Mobility, but I never tried it myself.